# Executing Python Script in PHP

Tags: php, python, twisted

I have written a simple chat program using `twisted` library in Python. Basically I have a server program(server.py) and a chat program ( client.py)

client.py is a simple python script which would connect to the server on a particular port and print the messages on the terminal.

I can run the server.py and the client.py on a local system and I can chat on different terminals.

I would like to integrate the client.py in PHP and be able to chat through the browser.

I am calling python script through `exec` in PHP. However it is not working.

```
exec("python client.py")
```

Any idea, if I am missing anything ?

Comment: "*it is not working.*": how?

Comment: I would like to start the chat between the users. If I execute the python script manually, I can do it

Comment: Are you under windows or linux/mac? In windows case you might try $tmp = exec(<path to python>\\python.exe C:\\wamp\\www\\python\\python client.py"

Comment: Note that some PHP environments disable or limit `exec`.

Comment: You know that you client.py will probably be bocking the PHP process which which will killed by the "webserver" sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can help you, but here's some things I'd consider:

- Have you tried executing a different command, does that work?
- Have you set the permissions of the .php file and Python.exe correctly?
- Can you run your command from a terminal window (either Windows/Mac/Linux) from the folder your PHP file is in?

If you've already tried all of these things, I can't think of another solution.. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following program helpful as a starting point. It is designed to run a Python program:

```
<?php

// Check that test is not FALSE; otherwise, show user an error.
function assert_($test)
{
    if ($test === FALSE)
    {
        echo '<html><head><title>Proxy</title></head><body><h1>Fatal Error</h1></body></html>';
        exit(1);
    }
}

// Patch this version of PHP with curl_setopt_array as needed.
if (!function_exists('curl_setopt_array')) {
    function curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options)
    {
        foreach ($curl_options as $option => $value) {
            if (!curl_setopt($ch, $option, $value)) {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
}

// Fetch the URL by logging into proxy with credentials.
function fetch($url, $proxy, $port, $user, $pwd)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    assert_($ch);
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_PROXY => $proxy . ':' . $port,
        CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH => CURLAUTH_NTLM,
        CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => $user . ':' . $pwd,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
    );
    assert_(curl_setopt_array($ch, $options));
    $transfer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    assert_($transfer);
    return $transfer;
}

// Run path with stdin and return program's status code.
function order($path, $stdin, &$stdout, &$stderr)
{
    $cmd = './' . basename($path);
    $descriptorspec = array(
        array('pipe', 'r'),
        array('pipe', 'w'),
        array('pipe', 'w')
    );
    $cwd = dirname($path);
    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $_REQUEST);
    assert_($process);
    for ($total = 0; $total < strlen($stdin); $total += $written)
    {
        $written = fwrite($pipes[0], substr($stdin, $total));
        assert_($written);
    }
    assert_(fclose($pipes[0]));
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    assert_($stdout);
    assert_(fclose($pipes[1]));
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    assert_($stderr);
    assert_(fclose($pipes[2]));
    return proc_close($process);
}

// Collect information to run over the proxy.
@ $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
@ $pwd = $_REQUEST['pwd'];

// Fetch the URL and process it with the backend.
$transfer = fetch('http://rssblog.whatisrss.com/feed/', 'labproxy.pcci.edu', 8080, $user, $pwd);
$status = order('/home/Chappell_Stephen/public_html/backend.py', $transfer, $stdout, $stderr);

// Check for errors and display the final output.
assert_(strlen($stderr) == 0);
echo $stdout;

?>
```